# Use of @since in PHP code

Tags: php, phpdoc, comments

I am using the @since comment in my PHP code. I have a question about its use though. Say I have a function that performs a particular task, and it's been implemented in version 1.0.

So I currently have @since 1.0.

Now I go ahead and change the function's name, although the code inside remains the same. 
Should it now say @since 3.0 (the current version) or remain @since 1.0?

Comment: anyone? I can provide more details if required.

Comment: i think you haven't did some research on google 
http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.since.pkg.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function name didn't exist in 1.0, therefore `@since` should be 3.0.  It's irrelevant that a differently-named function provided the same functionality in an old version; you wouldn't be able to use the new name in the old version.  The [docs](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/since.html) say:

> Use `@since` to document revisions, as in "This function has been a part of this package since version 2.0"

The purpose of `@since` is to tell someone using your package that "since version *x*, a function named `foo` exists.  If you go and change `foo` to `bar` in v3 but leave `@since` as v1, then your docs would incorrectly state that it's safe to call `bar()` in v1.  In fact, there was no `bar()` in v1, and the call would throw an error.

You might also consider keeping a function stub with the old name (which just calls the real function), and marking it [`@deprecated`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.deprecated.pkg.html).

Comment: This is correct, if the function called by that exact name is not in version 1.0, then it has not been there since 1.0.

Comment: I understand, thanks. What about if the name stays the same, but the contents of the function change drastically, how is that indicated?

Comment: @drtanz: The contents of your function may change drastically so long as *they implement the same functionality*.  For example, if `foo()` fetches some dataset, you might rewrite the function to return the data from a cache instead of running expensive database queries every time the function is called.  The code consuming your API doesn't care *how* the data is fetched, only that you provide the correct data.  Of course, you might note the change in the function's description: *"Since vX, this function caches the returned dataset. See {@link clearFoo()} if you need to clear the cached data."*

Comment: On the other hand, if you break your interface's contract by changing what the function does (now `foo()` deletes data instead of fetching it) or its signature (adding non-optional arguments), you should consider using a different name.

Answer (score 5):

The @since tag indicates at with which version did the associated Structural Elements became available.

*Syntax*

```
@since [version] [<description>]
```

The @since tag can be used to indicate since which version specific Structural Elements have become available.

This information can be used to generate a set of API Documentation where the consumer is informed which application version is necessary for a specific element.

The version MUST follow the same rules as the @version tag’s vector and MAY have a description to provide additional information.

This tag can occur multiple times within a PHPDoc. In that case, each occurrence is treated as an entry to a change log. It is RECOMMENDED that you also provide a description to each such tag.

*Example*

```
  /**
  * @since 1.0.1 First time this was introduced.
  *
  * @return integer Indicates the number of items.
  */
 function count()
 {
     <...>
 }

 /**
  * @since 1.0.2 Added the $b argument.
  * @since 1.0.1 Added the $a argument.
  * @since 1.0.0
  *
  * @return void
  */
 function dump($a, $b)
 {
     <...>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

since is a `phpDoc` tag

PHPDoc tags work with some editors to display more information about a piece of code. It is useful to developers using those editors to understand what the purpose and where they would use it in their code.

The convention for allowing PHPdoc blocks is to have @since information (even if not available at the time) and @package information, which should always be "WordPress" unless it is an external library. like following

```
/**
 * ... Description(s) here
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @since 2.1 or {@internal Unknown}}
 *
 * ... More information if needed.
 */
```

Please read following articles for more information on phpDoc tags

[PHPDocumentor 0.4.1](http://phpdocu.sourceforge.net/howto.php)

[Document when (at which version) an element was first added to a package](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.since.pkg.html)

[phpDocumentor Tutorial](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html)

[phpDocumentor tags - How to use tags in DocBlocks](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html)

[@since - phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/since.html)